# CFG for $L = \{w_1w_2 \cdots w_{2n} \mid n > 0, w_i \in \{a, b\}, 1 \leq i \leq 2n, w_j = b, w_{n + j} = a \ \exists j, 1 \leq j \leq n\}$

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, automata, context-free-grammar, formal-grammar

I think this is somehow related to the language describing all strings **not** of the form $ww, w \in \{a, b\}^*$, but I am still not quite sure how. Of course, I have done some thinking and it is evident that the string is just of the form
$$\underbrace{w_1w_2\cdots}_{\text{anything}}\underbrace{w_j}_{b}\underbrace{\cdots w_{n - 1}w_nw_{n + 1}w_{n + 2} \cdots }_{\text{anything}}\underbrace{w_{n + j}}_{a}\underbrace{\cdots w_{2n - 1}w_{2n}}_{\text{anything}}$$
When coming to SE, I usually have some work that I have started to go off of, however, I'm not even quite sure how to start on this one. How will the CFG ever know where exactly the indices $j$ and $n + j$ are? It is not clear to me where we can "build out" recursively on a string of this format. Any hints appreciated!

**Edit**: I am fairly certain that the CFG
\begin{align*}
            S &\rightarrow AB \mid BA \\
            A &\rightarrow aAb \mid bAa \mid aAa \mid bAb \mid a \\
            B &\rightarrow aBb \mid bBa \mid aBa \mid bBb \mid b
        \end{align*}
works. However, I am not yet entirely convinced intuitively if someone cares to explain.

Comment: I am puzzled by your definition. It looks like $ba \in L$, but $ab \notin L$. But your grammar is symmetrical in $a$ and $b$, and so is your conjecture on the first line.

Comment: You're right. I think the rule $S$ in the grammar should just be $S \rightarrow BA$. Then it seems to work fine.